# Installation of ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I am working on a development project with a number of other individuals using TortoiseSVN.  I followed http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act.ashx to install the toolkit.

I tried to have a look at the configuration for another project where Ajax control toolkit was installed however I have cannot get Ajax elements to appear in my solution explorer would anyone know why this might be? I had a look at this other person's solution explorer and they have the ajax control toolkit.dll, ajaxcontroltoolkit.pdb and other folders (ar, cs, de...) within a different type of folder (looks grey and has a cog symbol) called 'Bin'

I am using Visual Studio 2008, .Net Framework 3.5 and I tried the ajax control toolkit framework 3.5.

Can anyone offer some advice on what I have done wrong? Or can you provide another tutorial I can follow for the install

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Right click** on your toolbox
- **Choose Elements**  a dialog window will load (lasts a few seconds - just be  patient)
- register *.net frameworkComponents*
- **Browse** to your **AJAX Toolkit folder** and select *AjaxControlToolkit.dll*

That's it!

hth

Comment: Franz thank you for your response but this still did not seem to work. I read something about adding a reference? and then pointing it to the .dll file? is this correct?

Comment: After you add a control to your toolbox - you may add this one to your project/website. Afterwards the according dll will be added automatically to your project. @your post - what step did not work?

Comment: @Franz, I thought by doing what you had mentioned in your previous post, that it would bring the bin file into the solution explorer - this is what I had meant by it still did not seem to work. Even after I had added the Ajax controls to my toolbox in my project the bin file still did not appear. Maybe not having the bin file in the solution explorer isnt that big of a deal? but I was slightly worried when I had looked at someone else's project that had the toolkit installed and their setup included it.

Comment: you have to add a ToolkitScriptManager - by doing this - you will get all your files in your bin folder

Comment: glad that i could help - could you pls be so kind and mark this question as answered!!